# Why does "man muss das nicht" mean "you do not have to"?

Tags: german-to-english

Why does "man muss das nicht" mean "you do not have to"?

I thought *man* was a reference to multiple people, something like *alle*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Man" can also be translated "one"

So the translation would be:

> "One, does not have to"

I would even go so far as to say that the translation with "you" is incorrect.

Comment: It wasn't really my translation it's the one google translate gave me, thanks anyway :)

Comment: The translation with *you* is perfectly acceptable

Comment: edited it just now - thx

Answer (score 4):

*Man* is never a reference to multiple people. It corresponds to the English *one*

*Man muss das nicht* is best translated as either

> One does not have to do that

in elaborated speech, or

> You don't have to do that

in colloquial English. That's a [generic you](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_you) and doesn't refer to the person being adressed

The translation *one must not* would be incorrect here. That would correspond to the German *man darf nicht*

Answer (score 2):

English does not have a direct equivalent of German *man*. One possible word to express the same thing is *one*. Another, less formal, one is an [impersonal *you*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_you). This does not refer to the person who is being addressed.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why *man* and *one* aren't functionally equivalent? What makes them different?