# Can "einer" mean "you"? If so, in what context?

Tags: meaning

Remember vaguely that "einer" was used for "you".

Comment: There could be a situation when someone says _einer_ but particularly means you. But there's no general case that _einer_ can ever be translated with _you_.

Comment: Can you add an example sentence?

Comment: Related: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/39704/why-does-man-muss-das-nicht-mean-you-do-not-have-to/39708#39708

Comment: @Carsten Interessant die Assoziation mit _man_ kam mir auch gerade in den Sinn (s. Antwort).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean "*you"* as a third person singular indefinite pronoun? This would normally be translated with "*man*". E.g:

> **You** cannot walk on water" - "**man** kann nicht auf Wasser gehen".

You can however translate this pronoun with "ein(-en -em -es)" when it stands in a case other than the nominative:

> When someone isn't with **you**, he's against **you**. - Wenn jemand nicht
>   mit **einem** ist, ist er gegen **einen**.

Answer (score 3):

> #### Can “einer” mean “you”?

From your title, in direct translation no, "einer" would be translated to "one" or "someone".

In a certain context you might realize that someone said "einer" but meant yourself particularly, e.g.:

At the team meeting:

> *Boss:* **Einer** von Euch hatte letzte Woche vergessen die Küche aufzuräumen, das muss verbessert werden.

And everyone in the team knows that it was you, who forgot to do that duty. But because the Boss is a good one, and avoids blaming and finger-pointing in front of the team, he didn't say:

> *Boss:* **Du** hattest letzte Woche vergessen die Küche aufzuräumen, das muss verbessert werden.

---

One case I could think of though is something like the english word "one" is used like the german "man":

> **One** could try to use ...
> **Man** könnte versuchen ... zu benutzen

and then in a more personal dialogue

> **Du** könntest versuchen ... zu benutzen

But that's really all I can imagine, given such vague context.

Answer (score 2):

Es wird häufig ironisch verwendet, wenn sich aus der Gesprächssituation ergibt, dass der Sprecher nicht sich selbst meint, und sonst niemand da ist, der gemeint sein könnte.

> Einer könnte mal aufstehen und lüften.

Es bedeutet zwar *Du* in dieser Situation, gehört aber nicht mit *Du* übersetzt, will man die ironische Note erhalten.

Ein anderes Beispiel:

> X zu Y, der eine epische Rede führt: "Einer hat mal gesagt: „Fasse Dich kurz!“"

Answer (score 0):

> Na da hat aber einer nicht zugehört.

Or, even more ironically:

> Na da hat aber einer gut zugehört.

Both sentences are directly directed at a specific person (probably you), but the grammar doesn't reveal this at the first sight.